# how to access and upload big data to External storage via Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, capacity-planning, storage

We are in media agency and have Terabytes of data in storage but don't know how to manage it and access quickly and how to upload new data systematically,

We have sharepoint 2013 standard installed with builtin DB sql 2008 express, we are  just new to it, is there any way i can connect SharePoint 2013 with that External storage device / server via network and my users can access that data via sharepoint sites.Additionally they c they can upload new data via site upload.

How to display that data for easy access to our users.

Comment: still no solution or answer ? any idea how we can accomplish this task , even with SQL 2012 + SP 2013 Server ? please help

Comment: Is it something like [Overview of RBS in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748649.aspx) you're asking for? "This article describes how to use SharePoint 2013 together with Remote BLOB Storage (RBS) and SQL Server to optimize database storage resources."

Comment: Yes, Integration of Sharepoint with Big data is possible. Can you provide your storage/server details. like which vendor/company or what type of devices you are using?